# Limit and order collected nodes ranked by their total unique occurances

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been 'playing' with neo4j for a few weeks. It's amazing and I'm slowly getting to grips with it, and I now have a proper use case.

I'm taking exams in horticulture in a couple of weeks time. I need to know a fair number of plants by their characteristics or usage and the purpose of the graph is to find the smallest number of plants to learn (some apply to multiple questions)

In my graph these characteristics are (Feature) nodes

The exam has say 30 (Question)s.

Each (Question) has a [FIND]-> relationship to a (FeatureSet), with a {number} of how many examples of distinct plants it requires.

The (FeatureSet) [INCLUDES]-> one or more (Feature)s  - things like 'evergreen', 'tree', 'shrub'. 'bulb', 'winter-flowering', 'patio-plant'

(i.e. name 10 shrubs, 5 evergreen shrubs, 5 plants for a pot in winter)

I create a relationship (Plant)-[FEATURES]->(Feature) for each feature the plants in my database has.

I can run a query showing me ALL Plants matching ALL Features in the FeatureSet specified in the question

```
//SIMPLE RESULTS
MATCH (q:Question)-[find:FIND]->(fs:FeatureSet)

WITH fs, q, find.number as qNum
//GET ALL THE FEATURE SETS
MATCH (fInSet:Feature)<-[inc:INCLUDES]-(fs)
WITH fs, q , qNum, COLLECT(fInSet.feature) as fInSetList
MATCH (p:Plant)-[:FEATURES]->(fOfPlant:Feature)
WHERE fOfPlant.feature IN fInSetList
//Only plants matching all features
WITH fs, q , qNum, p, fInSetList, size(fInSetList) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT fOfPlant) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt

RETURN
q.id,
'Give ' + qNum + ' examples of ' + q.q as Question,
fInSetList as plantFeaturesReqd,
COLLECT(
p.name
)
as plantsFound
ORDER BY q.id
```

```
q.id    Question    plantFeaturesReqd   plantsFound
"1" "Give 1 examples of Evergreen Shrubs"   ["evergreen", "shrub"]  ["Rhododendron"]
"2" "Give 3 examples of Shrubs" ["shrub"]   ["Cornus", "Wych Hazel", "Buddleja", "Rhododendron"]
"3" "Give 1 examples of Deciduous Shrubs"   ["deciduous", "shrub"]  ["Cornus", "Wych Hazel"]
```

I can alter my RETURN statement to find how many times a plant appears in the total result set, which gives it a weighting when deciding to learn it or not:

```
RETURN
DISTINCT p.name as dName,
count(p.name) as dCount
ORDER BY dCount DESC
```

```
"Wych Hazel"    2
"Cornus"    2
"Rhododendron"  2
"Buddleja"  1
```

I can see from the results that I can get away with not learning Buddleja.

I want to achieve something like:

```
q.id    Question    plantFeaturesReqd   plantsFound
"1" "Give 1 examples of Evergreen Shrubs"   ["evergreen", "shrub"]  [{p:"Rhododendron", w:2}]
"2" "Give 3 examples of Shrubs" ["shrub"]   [{p:"Cornus",w:2}, {p:"Wych Hazel",w:2}, {p:"Rhododendron", w:2}, {p:"Buddleja",w:1}]
"3" "Give 1 examples of Deciduous Shrubs"   ["deciduous", "shrub"]  [{p:"Cornus",w:2}, {p:"Wych Hazel",w:2}]
```

and then get the correct [FIND{number}] of plants for each question, ordered by the weight`{w}`.

There's more than one option with the same weight I could learn for q3 (1 deciduous shrub), but I only need to learn about its deciduous feature, as I will already learn it is a shrub from q2 (2 shrubs).

Similarly, if I only had to learn 2 shrubs, it would be a toss-up between rejecting Cornus or Wych Hazel with the same weight.

So I would like (at a later stage) to adjust this weight for other reasons (eg. I can remember the latin name more easily, or I just like it!). Merging in those preferences must also avoid 'breaking' the choices for other questions.

Obviously with lots of questions (feature sets) and thousands of plants choices it makes more sense in practice.

[SVG of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgwMK.png)  (sorry, I can't upload SVG here & the png is poor)

CREATE.cypher

```
CREATE 
  (`0` :Feature {feature:'deciduous'}) ,
  (`1` :FeatureSet ) ,
  (`2` :Feature {feature:'shrub'}) ,
  (`3` :Feature {feature:'evergreen'}) ,
  (`5` :FeatureSet ) ,
  (`9` :Plant {name:'Rhododendron'}) ,
  (`13` :Question {id:'1',q:'Evergreen Shrubs'}) ,
  (`14` :Feature {feature:'semi-evergreen'}) ,
  (`15` :Plant {name:'Buddleja'}) ,
  (`16` :Question {id:'2',q:'Shrubs'}) ,
  (`17` :FeatureSet ) ,
  (`18` :Question {id:'3',q:'Deciduous Shrubs'}) ,
  (`19` :Plant {name:'Cornus'}) ,
  (`29` :Feature {feature:'winter-interest-flowers'}) ,
  (`30` :Plant {name:'Wych Hazel'}) ,
  (`1`)-[:`INCLUDES` ]->(`0`),
  (`1`)-[:`INCLUDES` ]->(`2`),
  (`5`)-[:`INCLUDES` ]->(`3`),
  (`5`)-[:`INCLUDES` ]->(`2`),
  (`9`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`2`),
  (`9`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`3`),
  (`13`)-[:`FIND` {number:1}]->(`5`),
  (`15`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`14`),
  (`15`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`2`),
  (`17`)-[:`INCLUDES` ]->(`2`),
  (`16`)-[:`FIND` {number:3}]->(`17`),
  (`18`)-[:`FIND` {number:1}]->(`1`),
  (`19`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`0`),
  (`19`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`2`),
  (`30`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`29`),
  (`30`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`0`),
  (`30`)-[:`FEATURES` ]->(`2`)
```

ARROWS.html

```html
<ul class="graph-diagram-markup" data-internal-scale="1" data-external-scale="1">
  <li class="node" data-node-id="0" data-x="-162.05996704101562" data-y="-608.8465919494629">
    <span class="caption">Feature</span><dl class="properties"><dt>feature</dt><dd>deciduous</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="1" data-x="-547.4232482910156" data-y="75.07541275024414">
    <span class="caption">FeatureSet</span>
  </li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="2" data-x="-1049.3427429199219" data-y="-608.8465919494629">
    <span class="caption">Feature</span><dl class="properties"><dt>feature</dt><dd>shrub</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="3" data-x="-2028.5903301239014" data-y="-608.8465919494629">
    <span class="caption">Feature</span><dl class="properties"><dt>feature</dt><dd>evergreen</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="5" data-x="-1586.3723907470703" data-y="44.78205490112305">
    <span class="caption">FeatureSet</span>
  </li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="9" data-x="-1549.8740997314453" data-y="-1406.8265972137451">
    <span class="caption">Plant</span><dl class="properties"><dt>name</dt><dd>Rhododendron</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="13" data-x="-1586.3723907470703" data-y="582.2714309692383">
    <span class="caption">Question</span><dl class="properties"><dt>id</dt><dd>1</dd><dt>q</dt><dd>Evergreen Shrubs</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="14" data-x="-2757.7551736831665" data-y="-641.2539367675781">
    <span class="caption">Feature</span><dl class="properties"><dt>feature</dt><dd>semi-evergreen</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="15" data-x="-2083.2289657592773" data-y="-1406.8265972137451">
    <span class="caption">Plant</span><dl class="properties"><dt>name</dt><dd>Buddleja</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="16" data-x="-1106.6406211853027" data-y="561.1691665649414">
    <span class="caption">Question</span><dl class="properties"><dt>id</dt><dd>2</dd><dt>q</dt><dd>Shrubs</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="17" data-x="-1106.6406211853027" data-y="44.78205490112305">
    <span class="caption">FeatureSet</span>
  </li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="18" data-x="-547.4232482910156" data-y="561.1691665649414">
    <span class="caption">Question</span><dl class="properties"><dt>id</dt><dd>3</dd><dt>q</dt><dd>Deciduous Shrubs</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="19" data-x="-677.7754373550415" data-y="-1343.9512340724468">
    <span class="caption">Plant</span><dl class="properties"><dt>name</dt><dd>Cornus</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="29" data-x="573.2279720306396" data-y="-608.8465919494629">
    <span class="caption">Feature</span><dl class="properties"><dt>feature</dt><dd>winter-interest-flowers</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="node" data-node-id="30" data-x="164.77948760986328" data-y="-1343.9512340724468">
    <span class="caption">Plant</span><dl class="properties"><dt>name</dt><dd>Wych Hazel</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="1" data-to="0">
    <span class="type">INCLUDES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="1" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">INCLUDES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="5" data-to="3">
    <span class="type">INCLUDES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="5" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">INCLUDES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="9" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="9" data-to="3">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="13" data-to="5">
    <span class="type">FIND</span><dl class="properties"><dt>number</dt><dd>1</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="15" data-to="14">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="15" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="17" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">INCLUDES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="16" data-to="17">
    <span class="type">FIND</span><dl class="properties"><dt>number</dt><dd>3</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="18" data-to="1">
    <span class="type">FIND</span><dl class="properties"><dt>number</dt><dd>1</dd></dl></li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="19" data-to="0">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="19" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="30" data-to="29">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="30" data-to="0">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
  <li class="relationship" data-from="30" data-to="2">
    <span class="type">FEATURES</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Updated

I have updated this with a simpler example, now containing a limited create script, arrows markup and link to SVG.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess the alternative is to reverse my thinking and from total unique result of possible plants, look at which / how many question they can answer?

Comment: Thanks for the edits @halfer.
Perhaps if I just made an abstract example ("widgets" with letters as "features") it would help to clarify..?

Comment: The original example and question have been updated (and hopefully simplified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some hours later....

This query gives me the result I want to essentially answer the question.

EDIT: Unfortunately, after further testing on a wider dataset, the sorting does still not work as expected, so this answer is not complete.

I can now work on customising alternative choices for plants with equal weights based on my preferences (I've only found ways not to do that correctly so far and it doesn't handle these cases at the moment).

```
//SIMPLE RESULTS
MATCH (q:Question)-[find:FIND]->(fs:FeatureSet)

WITH fs, q, find.number as qNum
//GET ALL THE FEATURE SETS
MATCH (fInSet:Feature)<-[inc:INCLUDES]-(fs)
WITH fs, q , qNum, COLLECT(fInSet.feature) as fInSetList
MATCH (p:Plant)-[:FEATURES]->(fOfPlant:Feature)
WHERE fOfPlant.feature IN fInSetList
//Only plants matching all features
WITH fs, q , qNum, p, fInSetList, size(fInSetList) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT fOfPlant) as cnt, 
collect(p.name) as pALL //** THIS IS IMPORTANT, BUT I DON'T UNDERSTAND QUITE WHY **//
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
WITH *, count(p) as pCnt
ORDER BY pCnt //** THIS RANKS BY WEIGHT BASED ON TOTAL OCCURRENCES **//
RETURN
q.id,
'Give ' + qNum + ' examples of ' + q.q as Question,
fInSetList as plantFeaturesReqd,
COLLECT(
p.name
)[0..qNum]  //** THIS LIMITS TO NUMBER REQUIRED PER QUESTION **//
as plantsFound
ORDER BY q.id
```

```
q.id    Question    plantFeaturesReqd   plantsFound
"1" "Give 1 examples of Evergreen Shrubs"   ["evergreen", "shrub"]  ["Rhododendron"]
"2" "Give 3 examples of Shrubs" ["shrub"]   ["Cornus", "Rhododendron", "Wych Hazel"]
"3" "Give 1 examples of Deciduous Shrubs"   ["deciduous", "shrub"]  ["Cornus"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly you're almost there, there are only 2 things missing.

1. sort by weight so that the grouping then keeps that weight
2. create and collect maps per question . collect({name:p.name, weight: weight})

   - Why is the question number on FIND?

Please try this query:

```
MATCH (q:Question)-[find:FIND]->(fs:FeatureSet)

WITH fs, q, find.number as qNum
//GET ALL THE FEATURE SETS
MATCH (fInSet:Feature)<-[inc:INCLUDES]-(fs)
WITH fs, q , qNum, COLLECT(fInSet.feature) as fInSetList
MATCH (p:Plant)-[:FEATURES]->(fOfPlant:Feature)
     WHERE fOfPlant.feature IN fInSetList
//Only plants matching all features
WITH fs, q , qNum, p, fInSetList, 
     size(fInSetList) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT fOfPlant) as cnt
     WHERE cnt = inputCnt
WITH *
// order by cnt == weight
ORDER BY cnt DESC
RETURN
q.id,
'Give ' + qNum + ' examples of ' + q.q as Question,
fInSetList as plantFeaturesReqd,
// collect maps
COLLECT({plant: p.name, weight: cnt}) as plantsFound
ORDER BY q.id
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry the property names aren't great. Question.id is the question number like in an exam (Q1a, 1b).

The property {number} on the [:FIND] relationship is how many (distinct) plants with that feature set are required for that question. Should really be {quantity}, 
FIND {quantity} examples of plants matching FeatureSet.

With your query, `cnt` is  returning a count of number of Features in the FeatureSet, in order to match only plants which have ALL Features required  (hence 1 for all plants in q2. ('shrub'), and 2 for all those both q1 & 3: 'deciduous' (or 'evergreen') AND 'shrub'

Comment: The value for weight is a count of relationships between the plant which is possible answer for the question and the questions it is a valid answer for.

Comment: What I can't seem to do is 'preserve' that value and use it when I slice the results into individual questions.

Comment: A bit like a JS reduce on the results for each question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object